# opencv format string

Tags: c++, opencv

pls help i have this code and i want to add to this x and y position

```
cv::Rect r = some thing;
std::cout << cv::format("%d, %s (%dx%d)\n", i+1, outfile.c_str(), r.width, r.height);
```

how to add x and y like this
iam try this but its didnt work

```
std::cout << cv::format("%d, %s (%dx%d)\n", i+1, outfile.c_str(), r.width, r.height, r.x, r.y);
```

i try it its not work

but when i add the r.x and r.y  and replace with r,height and r.width its work but i want the height and width and x and y

```
      std::cout << cv::format("%d, %s (%dx%d)\n", i+1, outfile.c_str(), r.x, r.y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add more format specifiers (one for each item):

```
std::cout << cv::format("%d, %s (%dx%d)(%d %d)\n", i+1, outfile.c_str(), r.width, r.height, r.x, r.y);
```

Comment: i know the problem with format but i add it like u and its didnt show the r.x and r.y its only show r.width and r.height

Comment: This solution should work. Are you sure you added the 2 more `%d` in the function ?

Comment: its work the problem here in preg_match 
how to accept more can u help me in php

if (preg_match('/\d+,\s*([^\s]+)\s+\((\d+)x(\d+)\)/i', $line, $m))

Comment: @medo zeus : you ask for help with a c++ problem here and in a comment  you then start asking for a specific php problem - seriously?

Comment: hhe no but actually i run this program with php :)

Comment: @medozeus, make your life easier, and remove all the '(' ')' ',' 'x' noise from the format string. your regexp will be a breeze then ;)